# Arrow keys on helm mini buffer

Tags: key-bindings, helm

I am a beginner of helm-mode.

Why remapping of arrow keys (`(kbd "<left>")`, `(kbd "right")`, ...) on `helm-map` doesn't work while others work fine?

Here are the entire settings:

```
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-;") 'helm-mini)
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-y") 'helm-show-kill-ring)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x C-r") 'helm-recentf)
(define-key global-map [remap find-file] 'helm-find-files) ;
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] 'helm-M-x)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<left>") 'backward-char)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<right>") 'forward-char)

;; no effects and default key bind works for following two lines
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<left>") 'backward-char)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<right>") 'forward-char)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `C-h k <right>` says it is on `helm-buffer-map`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Mapping `<right>` and `<left>` within `helm-map` like in your example works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I searched in GitHub repository by "left", then the problem solved by inserting `(setq helm-ff-lynx-style-map nil)` before `(helm-mode 1)`.

https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/91ced00ad8bac63ca1311a39b0045677f9b2caae/helm-files.el#L409

Hence my complete settings will be following:

```
(require 'helm-config)
(setq helm-ff-lynx-style-map nil)
(helm-mode 1)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-;") 'helm-mini)
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-y") 'helm-show-kill-ring)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x C-r") 'helm-recentf)
(define-key global-map [remap find-file] 'helm-find-files) ;
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] 'helm-M-x)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<left>") 'backward-char)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<right>") 'forward-char)
```

Comment: You can use C-f and C-b for `forward-char` and `backward-char` respectively. If you get used to them you'll find out that using arrows is much more time consuming for simple navigation. I think this is the reason why they're natively remapped to something else.

Comment: Yes, but I could not get used to them even in several years use.

Comment: have a look at [hardcore-mode](https://github.com/magnars/hardcore-mode.el). It's never too late to try again =)

Comment: Using emacs for decades. And no, using C-n etc is not easier for me since I use arrow keys in every other app under the sun and it's ingrained. Anyone not supporting arrows in edit lines by default needs to wake up to the real world ;)  Of course, add the facility to turn it off the truly Emacsed.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a more 'up-to-date' answer (for anyone new reading this):

Looking at the [helm source documentation](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-files.el) it seems that we should use customize, and it clearly states that declaring `helm-ff-lynx-style-map` manually with `setq` will not work...

I disagree, and this was found to be working fine:

```lisp
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)

;; to enable fuzzy matching with helm-mini, add the following settings:
(setq helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching t
      helm-recentf-fuzzy-match    t)

;; helm-find-files - file navigation on steroids!
;; if the point is located on a folder path, C-x C-f will
;; start in that folder. (Use C-l C-r to navigate directories)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)

;; move to end or beginning of source when reaching top or bottom
(setq helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source t)

;; use arrow keys to navigate helm-find-files menu
(setq helm-ff-lynx-style-map t)
(helm-mode 1)
```

Comment: Usually when a docstring says "use customize, setq won't work" it doesn't mean "we guarantee that `setq` won't work for you" but rather that if you use `setq` don't come complaining if it ends up not working.